# При нажатии на кнопку - добавить значение в input, при повторном нажатии - убрать

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, который при нажатии на ссылку добавляет некоторое значение в input. Вот он:

```html
<span><a name="menu-title" href="#" onclick="Zack(this);return false">Пепси</a></span><br /><br />
<span><a name="menu-title" href="#" onclick="Zack(this);return false">Колу</a></span><br /><br />
<span><a name="menu-title" href="#" onclick="Zack(this);return false">Спрайт</a></span><br /><br />

<input class="foxtext" type="text" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.title;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.title) this.value='';" name="zakaz" style="width:235px !important;" title="Что хотите заказать?" value="Что хотите заказать?">

<script type="text/javascript">
var First = true;
function Zack (MenuTitl) {
    var zakaz = document.getElementsByName('zakaz')[0];
    var dop=zakaz.value+', ';
     if(First) {First=false;dop="";}
    zakaz.value = dop + MenuTitl.innerHTML;            
}

</script>
```

А как его допилить, чтобы при повторном клике на ссылку, это значение из inputa удалялось? То есть, к примеру, жмякнул "Пепси" один раз - добавилось, жмякнул снова - удалилось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так сделать:

```js
var order = [];
function Zack(MenuTitl) {
    var zakaz = document.getElementsByName('zakaz')[0];
    var item = MenuTitl.innerHTML;
    if (order.includes(item)) order.splice(order.indexOf(item),1);
    else order.push(item);
    zakaz.value = order.join(', ');            
}
```

```html
<span><a name="menu-title" href="#" onclick="Zack(this);return false">Пепси</a></span><br /><br />
<span><a name="menu-title" href="#" onclick="Zack(this);return false">Колу</a></span><br /><br />
<span><a name="menu-title" href="#" onclick="Zack(this);return false">Спрайт</a></span><br /><br />

<input class="foxtext" type="text" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.title;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.title) this.value='';" name="zakaz" style="width:235px !important;" title="Что хотите заказать?" value="Что хотите заказать?">
```

Comment: все работает, спасибо! А ещё помогите, пожалуйста. Если в inpute на момент открытия страницы уже что-то введено (вручную, или из БД), то при клике на любую ссылку, удаляются все значения. Хотелось бы, чтобы удалялось только то значение, на которое кликнули.

Comment: Можно тогда начальное значение заказов брать из инпута:
var order=document.getElementsByName('zakaz')[0].innerHTML.split(', ');